# Embed facebook live_videos tab in iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

I've looked at the Facebook page plugin to embed pages or tabs found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

There they show how to embed pages and tabs. Eg:

```
<iframe
src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage/&tabs=timeline"
frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"
allowfullscreen="true"
height="1000px"
width="100%">
</iframe>
```

They list some of the tabs that can be rendered such as timeline, events, messages. However, it does not work for the tab called live_videos.

Is there ANY way I could embed https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage/live_videos/ without creating a facebook app?

Comment: That parameter only works for the three tabs mentioned in the page plugin documentation. // You can embed _specific_ live videos using the Embedded Videos plugin - but there is nothing to automatically _list_ a page’s live videos, or have it dynamically “fetch” the address of the most recent one. Anything like that, you would have to develop yourself.

Comment: @CBroe was afraid of that. Their tabs description sounds like more could be added. Oh well, was worth a shot. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a workaround. The reason for my original question was that I only want to embed live stream and previous live stream videos.

Facebook has an option to [make the live url static:](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/629164494303277?id=1123223941353904)

When this is done, the facebook tab parameter 'live' can be used:

```html
<iframe
src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/YourFBPageName/live"
frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"
allowfullscreen="true"
height="1000px"
width="100%">
</iframe>
```